# How to mock AsyncPolicyWrap or AsyncPolicy in .Net Core using FakeItEasy

Tags: c#, .net, moq, polly, fakeiteasy

I have a code like this (I have to test a repo, you'll see the code below)

```
public class SomeClass
{
    public AsyncPolicyWrap PropName { get; }
    
    public SomeClass(...)
    {     
        PropName = Policy.WrapAsync(someRetry,someCircuitBreaker)
        // here there are passed some methods that return someRetry - AsyncRetryPolicy  
        // and  someCircuitBreaker - AsyncCircuitBreakerPolicy  
    }
}
```

then I have another repo class

```
public class SomeRepo : ISomeRepo
{
    private readonly AsyncPolicy _somePolicy;
    
    public SomeRepo(..., SomeClass someClass) : base(...)
    {
        _somePolicy = someClass.PropName;
    }
    public async Task<Result<SomeDTO>> GetDTO(Guid someId)
    {
        var someResponse = await _somePolicy.ExecuteAsync(() =>
            HttpClient.GetAsync(serviceName, $"endpointUrl"));
        ...
    }
}
```

2 pieces of code above can't be changed cause they are in prod and I as a junior dev just have to cover code with tests if possible

I have tried to write a test like this

```
[TestMethod] 
public async Task DoStuff()
{
    var repository = DefaultSome();

    var result = await repository.GetDTO(new Guid());

    result.ShouldNotBeNull(); // don't pay attention I'll change stuff which has to be asserted
}
private SomeRepo DefaultSome(Some some = null) 
{
    some = some ?? A.Fake<ISome>();
    /// HERE I TRIED TO MOCK STUFF IN DIFFERENT WAYS AND I HAVE AN ERROR
    var policyWrap = A.Dummy<AsyncPolicyWrap>();
    //var test = Policy.WrapAsync(A.Fake<AsyncRetryPolicy>(), A.Fake<AsyncCircuitBreakerPolicy>());
    //var test = Policy.WrapAsync(A.Fake<IAsyncPolicy>(), A.Fake<IAsyncPolicy>());

    A.CallTo(() =>
            policyWrap.ExecuteAsync(A<Func<Task<HttpResponseMessage>>>._))
        .Returns(new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK));

    var policy = A.Fake<RetryPolicies>();
    A.CallTo(() =>
            policy.PropName)
        .Returns(policyWrap);

    return new SomeRepo(some, ..., policy);
}
```

here is an error i get
[image: The error itself]

I get similar for commented // var test = ...    variats

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Concrete vs Abstract

Whenever you need to mock something then rely on abstraction rather than concrete implementation.

[`AsyncPolicyWrap`](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly/blob/174cc53e17bf02da5e1f2c0d74dffb4f23aa99c0/src/Polly/Wrap/AsyncPolicyWrap.cs) is a concrete class not an `abstract` like [`AsyncPolicy`](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly/blob/174cc53e17bf02da5e1f2c0d74dffb4f23aa99c0/src/Polly/AsyncPolicy.cs)

Also as the exception says this class does not have a public parameterless constructor.
It has an `internal` ctor with 2 parameters:

```
internal AsyncPolicyWrap(AsyncPolicy outer, IAsyncPolicy inner)
    : base(outer.ExceptionPredicates)
{
    _outer = outer;
    _inner = inner;
}
```

So, you should prefer `AsyncPolicy` `abstract` class or [`IAsyncPolicy`](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly/blob/174cc53e17bf02da5e1f2c0d74dffb4f23aa99c0/src/Polly/IAsyncPolicy.cs) interface.

#### With or without result

Please be aware that in Polly each Policy has two versions:

- One which does not return any result
- One which does return some result

Based on the `SomeRepo`'s code your Policy should return an `HttpResponseMessage`.

So, you should use `IAsyncPolicy<HttpResponseMessage>` or `AsyncPolicy<HttpResponseMessage>` to indicate that your policy will return an `HttpResponseMessage`.

#### Mocking

Whenever you mock an `IAsyncPolicy<HttpResponseMessage>` then you don't have to recreate the combined policy (like you did in the comments). All you have to do is to define how should the `ExecuteAsync` behave.

Happy path:

```
var mockedPolicy = new Mock<IAsyncPolicy<HttpResponseMessage>>();
mockedPolicy
    .Setup(policy => policy.ExecuteAsync(It.IsAny<Func<Task<HttpResponseMessage>>>()))
    .ReturnsAsync(new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK));
```

Unhappy path:

```
var mockedPolicy = new Mock<IAsyncPolicy<HttpResponseMessage>>();
mockedPolicy
    .Setup(policy => policy.ExecuteAsync(It.IsAny<Func<Task<HttpResponseMessage>>>()))
    .ThrowsAsync(new HttpRequestException("Something bad happened"));
```

I've used moq to mock the policy but the same concept can be applied for FakeItEasy.